# Can I set a default hostname for curl?

Tags: curl

I would like to reduce the keystrokes when I use curl to test web services on my workstation.

Is there a way to set a default hostname of 'localhost:3000' into ~/.curlrc so the following will work?

```
curl /foo.json
```

Answer (score 1):

On Unix – shell functions:

```
cu() { curl "http://localhost:3000/$1"; }
```

`cu foo.json` would be translated to `curl http://localhost:3000/foo.json`.

Downside: needs far more code to support options (`curl -I` and stuff), but that can be achieved too.